# NoReverseMatch at /products/ "adding products to the basket"

Tags: django

I am fairly new and working on a project and want to just add products to the basket
I have struggled with this for a few days and just don't know what to do to make it work.
can anybody help me or refer me to some page that can help me?
Thank You

NoReverseMatch at /products/
Reverse for 'addtobasket' with arguments '('Python Tutorial',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['productapp/\.\./basket/$']

models:

```
class Products(models.Model):
    products_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    inventory = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    product_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to ='images/', default='images/broken/broken.png')

    def __str__(self):
        if (self.inventory<=0):
            return self.products_name + ' (Out of Stock)'
        return self.products_name

class Basket(models.Model):
    products = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.products)
```

urls:

```
app_name = 'productapp'
urlpatterns = [
    path('products/', views.products, name='products'),
    path('basket/', views.basket, name ='basket'),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('../basket/', views.addtobasket, name='addtobasket'),
]
```

views:

```
def products(request):
    products_list = Products.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    context = {'products_list': products_list}
    return render(request, 'productapp/products.html', context)

def basket(request):
    basket_list = Basket.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    context = {'basket_list': basket_list}
    return render(request, 'productapp/basket.html', context)

def addtobasket(request, name):
    basket = Basket.objects.all()
    product = Products.objects.get(products_name=name)
    basket.products.add(product)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("basket"))
```

html:

```
<body>
    <section>
        {% block content %}
            {% if products_list %}
                {% for product in products_list %}
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <p>{{product.products_name}}</p>
                            <p>{{product.price}}</p>
                            <a href="{% url 'productapp:addtobasket' product.products_name %}" id="addtobasket" value="product.products_name">Add to Basket</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>]
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                <p>No products avalable at this moment.</p>
            {% endif %}
        {% endblock %}

    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: A path with `../` makes not much sense, since that means the url should contain the dots. Furthermore you should specify the URL parameter in the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A path with `../` makes not much sense, since that means the url should contain the dots.

Furthermore you should specify the URL parameter in the path:

```
app_name = 'productapp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('products/', views.products, name='products'),
    path('basket/', views.basket, name ='basket'),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('basket/add/<str:name>/', views.addtobasket, name='addtobasket'),
]
```

Adding an item to the basket should *not* work with a GET request, since the HTTP protocol specifies that GET requests should *not* have side-effects. You will need to work with a POST request, for example by implementing a mini-form with `method="post"`, or through an AJAX post request.

Comment: Thank u very much.  i has been fix sorry to bother you again but now but after clicking the add to basket I'm getting this "AttributeError at /productapp/basket/add/Python Tutorial/"

Comment: @Omid: `baket` is not a single basket, it is a *collection* (`QuerySet`) of zero, one or more `Basket`,s, so you can not use `basket.products.add(...)`. You will have to fetch the basket (of the logged in user).

Comment: I don't know what's that means and how to do that but thank you so much. I am gonna try to find out and maybe fix it. and if you have any suggestions that how can I learn to do that, please tell me. thank u again